# Angular Bootstrap Lightbox Parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, lightbox

I integrated the AngularJS module [angular-bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox) in my project and it's working fine.

I can click on the thumnail and the lightbox opens with the image.
Now I would like to send one additional parameter to the lightbox modal.
Has anybody implemented this with the mentioned plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the angular-boostrap-lightbox project, i see that apparently you can do that. Take a look [here](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/blob/master/src/lightbox-service.js#L253) at the source of the openModal function on Github. You have to add a third parameter, like so:

```
Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index, additionalParameters);
```

Comment: I already took a look in the projects code and saw this additionalParameter. But how can I access this param on the modal view?

Comment: The purpose of the third parameter in `Lightbox.openModal()` is to pass in to options to the [Bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), options such as `windowClass` or `animation`.

If instead what you want is to access some variable in a template, you can write a controller to do that.